# How do I get the size of file in disk?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-10

How do I get the size of file in disk? as show in the Windows explorer? e.g, a filename has:

```
size: 172 bytes (172 bytes)
size on disk: 0 bytes
```

But my application shows:

```
GetDiskFreeSpace(L"C:\\" &sectorsPerCluster, &lpBytesPerSector,
            &numberOfFreeClusters, &totalNumberOfClusters));
    int TotalSize = lpBytesPerSector * ((fileLength + lpBytesPerSector - 1) / lpBytesPerSector);
    printf("fileLength = %d\n", fileLength);
    printf("TotalSize = %d\n", TotalSize);
```

it output:

```
fileLength = 172
TotalSize = 512
```

What am I missing to compute properly the size in disk of the filename?

Comment: seems like the windows version is the wrong one. A file of 172 bytes cannot have 0 size on disk, seems like they have rounded down the number of sectors when = 1

Comment: The file is corrupted. This is what I'm trying to determine. Does this count?

Comment: You can try calling `stat`.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I'm on Windows. Is this an UNIX-only function?

Comment: @Jack I think there are Windows versions, but I'm not sure, and I'm not sure they'd tell you anything different than your `GetDiskFreeSpace()` call.  But it might be worth a try.

Comment: Raymond Chen wrote a blog article on this topic: [How does Explorer calculate “Size on disk”?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160427-00/?p=93365). In the case where the size is rounded to the nearest sector, try this algorithm instead: `DWORD TotalSize = (fileLength + (lpBytesPerSector - 1)) & ~(lpBytesPerSector - 1);` Though you should use a 64-bit file size to handle files > 4GB.

Comment: Jack, you should be using bytes per _cluster_, not bytes per sector.  @Remy I think Raymond's post is mainly talking about various edge-cases.  For regular (non-compressed) files, the above code (when corrected) should be pretty close.

Comment: `512` looks like the right calculated result. Apparently Windows 10 uses a different method to find the size on disk, which fails for corrupted file.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but I think I have an answer.

Windows Explorer maybe shows the right info.

On NTFS, small file data can be embedded into MFT (Master File Table). Master File Table is the system file that contains information about every file on disk (including itself, yes). The information is stored in MFT entries, usually 1024 bytes. Usually there's the file name and where to find its data. But for smaller files, the data can be stored in MFT itself.

Other file systems might also employ some way of embedding small files into FS metadata. FAT/FAT32/exFAT do not, but I don't know about ReFS.

It is logical not to count the data in FS structures as size on disk, since for larger files name also doesn't count.

Other reasons for size on disk to be smaller than size is compressed or sparse files.

I don't know how Explorer obtains this information, but you can use `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS` IOCTL to obtain file locations on disk, then parse the resulting `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER`. It is complex, but I don't know an easier way. I tried out `GetCompressedFileSize`, but it still returns nonzero file size for in-MFT files.

[Article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160427-00/?p=93365) linked in comment says in **Bonus chatter**

> Starting in Windows 8.1, the Size on disk calculation includes the sizes of alternate data streams and sort-of-kind-of tries to guess which streams could be stored in the MFT and not count them toward the size on disk. (Even though they really are on disk. I mean, if they’re not on disk, then where are they?)

It is not specified what means *sort-of-kind-of-tries-to-guess*, but with `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS` you can have precise answer.